# Stack Overflow rating, any advantage to fresh graduates?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I think that users here are spanning across all companies in US and worldwide. Will Stack Overflow rating add value to the resume? Are there any specific tags, graduates should be focusing on?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable

Answer (score 2):

There's always a lot of value to maintaining an active role in the community, so continue participating.  At the same time, though, I'd suggest targeting your resume specifically to the organization you're applying to.  Different organizational cultures will value different information, and your research into the organization should give you a clue as to the sort of culture that might be predominant there.

For example, if you're applying to a relatively small company that research indicates has an active role in the software industry, it might be interesting to put your stackoverflow user name and rep score on there so that they can check you out.  If, on the other hand, you're throwing your resume into a cubicle farm (a la IBM), the person reviewing your resume is more likely to look at the number, think "what the heck is that?" and toss it out.

Either way, you can leverage stackoverflow when you get an interview to prove that you are an interested an active participant in the industry and that you remain abreast of relevant technologies on your own time (a good selling point regardless of the company, as far as I'm concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30578/is-stack-overflow-reputation-marketable).